# Cannot connect to windows8 using nautilus/smb

Tags: nautilus, windows-8, smb

In nautilus (running ubuntu 13.04) I am trying to connect to a windows8 machine using the following url:

```
smb://user@xxx.xx.xx.xxx
```

Followed by entering the password that I also use when doing a remote desktop connection.

But I get:

```
Unhandled error message: Failed to retrieve share list from server: Connection timed out
```

Do I need to configure something on ubuntu/window8 to establish a connection using smb?

I have tried to follow this guide:

http://www.noobslab.com/2012/03/configure-samba-sharing-between-ubuntu.html#windows_to_ubuntu

And share a folder on the windows8 machine, but still get the same error as above.

From commandline I have also tried to mount it manually:

```
root@ubuntu:/mnt/win8# mount -t cifs -o username=user //xxx.xx.xx.xxx/sharedfolder /mnt/win8/
```

But I get:

```
mount error(115): Operation now in progress
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

which is not that helpful.

If I run:

```
smbtree -b -N
```

I don't see the machine that I would like to mount. Only a bunch of printers and my own local virtual machines.

Answer (score 0):

Okay here's things to check.

### On your Windows PC

1. Check that File and Print services is checked in protocols on your network interface you expect other computers to connect on. I know this screen is from Win7 but the dialog is the same in Win8

   [image]

   **Sharing and Connect**,

   *This section is basically lifted from [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows-8/turn-sharing-on-or-off) put the relevant info here incase Microsoft decide to pull the page.*
2. Windows 8 asks you when you first join a network if you want to enable sharing for that network.

   To turn sharing and connect on or off.

   2. View a list of available networks by swiping in from the right edge of the screen, tapping Settings (or if you're using a mouse, pointing to the upper-right corner of the screen, moving the mouse pointer down, and then clicking Settings), and then tapping or clicking the network icon (Wireless network icon or Wired network icon).
   3. Press and hold or right-click the network you're connected to, then tap or click Turn sharing on or off.

   **Network Discovery,**

   Windows 8 can let turn sharing on but discovery off.
3. Network discovery is a setting that affects whether your computer can see (find) other computers and devices on the network and whether other computers on the network can see your computer. It's one of several settings that are turned on when you turn on network sharing. You can turn network discovery on or off independently of network sharing,

   **Firewalls**
4. Check your windows firewall and 3rd party firewalls that SMB is allowed through.  I think Windows 8 will take care of the Windows firewall by doing steps 2 and 3 but doesn't hurt to check.

Comment: I can verify that 1) is as you recommend. And in 2) I have also turned Network sharing on. But I get the same error as before.